# Webdriver C# - RemoteWebDriver returns Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am trying to write a test using C# under Mac. I was able to run tests on Chrome, but now I am going to the next step, by trying to initialize Internet Explorer located on a Windows VM I am using. 
So in the VM I started first the selenium standalone server with the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.3.0.jar -role hub
```

Then, I connected a hub to it from the same VM:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverSetup.exe selenium-server-standalone-3.3.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.1.4:4444/grid/register
```

I see from the logs that the node registers to the hub and listens for events and also am able to see in the hub's log that the node has registered.
192.168.1.4 is the IP if the Windows VM, where host the hub and note are located

Until now everything seems to be fine, now I write the following C# code to connect to hub: 
`

```
private  IWebDriver driver;
try {
    DesiredCapabilities ip = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
    Uri URL = new Uri("http://192.168.1.4:4444");
    driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(URL, ip);
catch (Exception e) {
   string stack = e.StackTrace;
}
```

`

When executing the code I get the following error: 
`

```
{System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession (OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) [0x00048] in <3440d4b964694e75ab172947d6b08035>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor (OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) [0x0001e] in <3440d4b964694e75ab172947d6b08035>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor (System.Uri remoteAddress, OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, System.TimeSpan commandTimeout) [0x00008] in <3440d4b964694e75ab172947d6b08035>:0 
  at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor (System.Uri remoteAddress, OpenQA.Selenium.ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) [0x00000] in <3440d4b964694e75ab172947d6b08035>:0 
  at SeleniumCheck.BrowserDriver..ctor () [0x000d9] in
```

`

I tried with Webdriver and Internet explorer versions 3.1.0, 3.3.0 and 3.4.0
I get the same error.

Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong? Doesn't seem to be a cast I am doing. the issue occurs at this line: 
    `driver =  new RemoteWebDriver(URL, ip);` 
I even tried 
    `driver =  (IWebDriver)new RemoteWebDriver(URL, ip);`, but still the same.
It's the same if I try initializing Firefox. I am pretty sure it's not the IE capabilities. I get the same thing if i use 
    `DesiredCapabilities.Firefox()`

Comment: Try this uri instead: `http://192.168.1.4:4444/wd/hub`

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks for the suggestion. I tried also your approach, but now I'm getting `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b0] in `